# How to dynamically allocate a two dimensional array of pointers ? (C)

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, malloc

I have an assignment to make a dictionary.
It will contain an x amount of words and their definitions (input by user).
Instructions say that the dictionary should be of type char*** (2D array of pointers=arrays=strings), but I've got absolutely no idea of how to dynamically allocate the size of the array. it should have 2 lines, 1 for words and another 1 for their definitions, and the number of columns is decided by how many words are in the dictionary. While looking for help online i came up with this:

```
char** AllocateArray(int line, int column)
{
    char** pArray=(char**)malloc(line*sizeof(char*));
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++) 
        pArray[i]=(char*)malloc(column*sizeof(char));

    return pArray;
}
```

What changes should i make in the code for it to work with my char*** ?
Using Visual studio 2012

Edit:

I have a problem with this right now:

```
void inputString(char* p1)
{
    char buffer[80];
    printf("\nEnter a word:");
    scanf("%s",buffer);
    p1=(char*)malloc(strlen(buffer)+1);
    if(p1!=NULL)
    {
        strcpy(p1,buffer);
        free(buffer);
    }
}
```

it crashes right after i input a word. the char* that the function receives is dictionary[i][j]. –

Comment: Being a "three star programmer" is not usually considered a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

Don't `free()` anything allocated on the stack (i.e. `buffer`). 
Also, your function `inputString()` will not tell its client what memory it had allocated, since  `p1` is local to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

```
char*** dictionary;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int lines = 10;
dictionary = (char***)malloc(sizeof(char**)*lines);

for(i=0;i<lines;i++)
{
    dictionary[i] = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*4);
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        dictionary[i][j] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*25);
}
```

You have to modify the malloc's parameters in order to adapt to your problem/ or modify them when you need more memory for your strings.
Also it might be a good idea to try and free memory when you do not need it

Comment: [You Shouldn't cast the results of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)

Comment: I agree that in C (and not C++) it is not necessary, but writing the casts at least while he's a beginner in dynamic memory allocation is a good practice, because it helps him understand better pointers (which are his main problem).

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to malloc like this...

```
dictionary[i][j] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(word_to_insert)+1);
```

...because each word end with a supplementary byte filled with 0 "null terminate string".

Answer (score 0):

a sample

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char ***dictionary;
    const char *words[] = { "ASEAN", "United Nations", "OPEC" };
    size_t howManyWords = sizeof(words)/sizeof(*words);
    int i;

    dictionary = malloc(howManyWords*sizeof(char**));
    printf("Please enter the definition of this word\n");
    for(i = 0; i < howManyWords; ++i){
        char buff[80];
        char **keyValue;

        printf("%s : ", words[i]);
        fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin);
        keyValue = malloc(2*sizeof(char*));
        keyValue[0] = (char*)words[i];
        keyValue[1] = malloc(strlen(buff)+1);
        strcpy(keyValue[1], buff);
        dictionary[i] = keyValue;
    }

    //print
    for(i=0;i<howManyWords;++i){
        printf("%s : %s", dictionary[i][0], dictionary[i][1]);
    }
    //release
    for(i=0;i<howManyWords;++i){
        free(dictionary[i][1]);
        free(dictionary[i]);
    }
    free(dictionary);
    return 0;
}
```